# Change nil's to zeroes in elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp, null, zero

I'd like to ask - what is the function doing nil conversion from nil's to zeroes in elisp?

I'm a newbie and I think I am inventing the wheel with my code:

```
(defun chgnull (x)
  (if (null x) 0 1))
(mapcar 'chgnull '(1 2 nil))
```

Search through Emacs sources by keyword "to zero" and such haven't shown anything relevant.

Comment: What you wrote looks good, what is it you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well, actually I thought function like my chgnull already exists somewhere in Emacs :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression `(or x 0)` will evaluate to 0 if `x` is nil, and `x` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, Sean. I think your piece of code is even more useful.